# AWS Cloudformation SAM: how avoid include folder in Esbuild bundle for with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I've a typescript lambda configured through CloudFormation:

```
  MigrationLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub ${AppName}-${Env}-migration
      CodeUri: ../src
      Handler: migration_lambda.lambdaHandler
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: false
        Bundle: false
        EntryPoints:
            - ./lambdas/internals/migration_lambda.ts
        SourcesContent: true
        External:
            - pg-native
            - reflect-metadata
            - mysql
            - oracledb
            - pg-query-stream
            - better-sqlite3
            - sqlite3
            - tedious
            - mysql2
            - dotenv
            - "./temp"
            - src/migrations/*
            - /migrations/*
            - ./migrations/*
            - ../migrations/*
            - ./migrations
```

the problem is that inside my src folder I've a knex migration folder

```
- /src
-- /lambdas
----/internals
-------migration_lambda.ts
-- /migrations
----migration_1.js
----migration_2.js
```

when I build my code, esbuild take all this files and generate a single bundle...if I print "ls" inside my lambda I just can see a migration_lambda.js...all the files and folder structures are replaced with a build...

But this is a problem, because I need that esbuild respect this folder and the files inside this...in order to make the migrations

As you can see I tried defining several externals but none of them work for me...do you know how can ignore this migration folder from the esbuild process?

thanks

Comment: This https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/308 might be helpful, check if you cannot ignore some files thanks to your `.npmignore`